# Everything opens in Archive manager

Tags: archive

Everything I've tried to install has opened in Archive manager. Even if the file says that it's executable it still opens in archive manager. There aren't any executable files inside the archive either. There also isn't any other software to open the files with. How do I make it so it opens an installer instead of the archive.

Comment: What type of files do these occur with? Is there anything in the archive?

Comment: With all the info that you give us, I imagine that you've downloaded a `.tar.gz` file and trying to install it doing double click. Those files (`*.tar.gz`) are not executable, they have the source code of the app. To *install* it you need to *compile* first. If this is your case, you will find all the necessary information [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/25961/62483). Let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: I'm trying to install a .tar.gz and a .jar

Answer (score 1):

as for the tar.gz files you should have a look at the [question linked in the commends](https://askubuntu.com/q/25961/176889)

the .jar file has to be run in a java runtime environment, so if you don't have it already install the program OpenJDK (search in the software center).

Now you need to set the permissions on the file to allow to execute it. to do this right click the file, and select properties. now open the permissions tab and check the 'Allow executing file as program' check box.